# How to check if datatable.PrimaryKey is set

Tags: datatable, primary-key

i have a datatable which i have to assign a primary key if it doesn't already have one. i tried :

```
if (ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey == null)
{
    ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Naam"] };
}
```

But the PrimaryKey (in this case) not null. When i checked it contained : {System.Data.DataColumn[0]} How can i check on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not that hard after all i already tried this but apparently did something wrong because when i just tried again it did work :

```
    DataColumn[] esl = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Naam"] };
    if (ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey == null || ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey == esl)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Naam"] };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Javier's answer is correct, but lacks explanation. So here it is, DataTable.PrimaryKey property is collection of DataColumns.
If the DataTable PrimaryKey property is not set than length of the collection will be 0. If DataTable has one or more fields defined as primary key than length of the PrimaryKey property will reflect this.
So, checking like this:

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey.Length == 0)
```

will tell us if no columns are added to represent the primary key, and the part

```
     ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Naam"] };
```

would actually add DataColumn(s) to collection of columns held by PrimaryKey property.

Comment: Hello, please add some formatting to your answer so this is more readable.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey.Length == 0)
    ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["Naam"] };
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.